# Referring to a table by variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I'm sure this is pretty basic, but how do I set up an INSERT statement using a variable for the table name?

For example, I have a number of input files, all configured identically (Input1, Input2, Input3, ...) all going to an INSERT or MERGE statement.

I want to either do a loop, working through all the input files, or call the INSERT statement as a function

```
INSERT INTO [OutputFile]
SELECT i.*
FROM   [<Input Variable>] i
     LEFT JOIN [OutputFile] OP
         ON CONCAT(i.Field1, i.Field6) = CONCAT(OP.Field1, OP.Field6) 
     WHERE OP.Field1 IS NULL 

PRINT 'Number of rows added is ' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT as char(6));
```

I'll actually be using MERGE statements, but I assume the process will be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how do I set up an INSERT statement using a variable for the table name?

You don't, not directly with SQL. Table names and column names cannot be variables.

You can achieve this by using [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), but you have to be careful not to introduce [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) is a fantastic in depth article discussing dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL.  The `QUOTENAME()` function will use and escape square brackets to help prevent SQL injection.

```
declare @table sysname = 'MyTable';

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
    INSERT INTO [OutputFile]
    SELECT i.*
    FROM {{table}} i
    LEFT JOIN [OutputFile] OP
        ON (CONCAT(i.Field1, i.Field6)
            = CONCAT(OP.Field1, OP.Field6))
    WHERE OP.Field1 IS NULL
    ';

set @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '{{table}}', QUOTENAME(@table));

exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do a loop?  Just use `union all`:

```
insert into OutputFile
    select i.*
    from ((select * from input1) union all
          (select * from input2) union all
          . . .
          (select * from inputn)
         ) i left outer join
         OutputFile op
         on CONCAT(i.Field1, i.Field6) = CONCAT(OP.Field1, OP.Field6) 
    WHERE OP.Field1 IS NULL
```

If there are lot of tables, you can put them in a column in Excel and use Excel formulas to create the query.